# "Any" data type for GraphQL Query Return Type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I am a bit new to Typescript and am having some issues with data types. I was told that I should avoid using the 'any' data type since it negates the whole point of using Typescript. However, I am unable to change the data types. For example,

when I run a GraphQL query, I use this:

```
   login({
      variables: {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
        setShouldRedirect(true);
        //props.history.push("/panel");
      })
```

The `data.loginEmail.accessToken`is a string so I changed `:any`to string but I get errors that:

```
Argument of type '({ data }: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ExecutionResult<any>) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'ExecutionResult<any>' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2345
```

If I change the type to `object`, I get `Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339` but the documentation also says that the mutation returns an object. So if not object or string, how else could I specify the data type for such an object? Is it even possible?

Similarly, when I map items like this after a query:

```
{data &&
          data.users.nodes &&
          data.users.nodes.map((c: any, i: any) => (
            <li key={i}>
              Id: {c.id}, First Name: {c.firstName}, Last Name: {c.lastName},
              Email: {c.email}, phoneNumber: {c.phoneNumber}
            </li>
          ))}
```

How else could I specify c and I? There's no simple integer option for i.

Edit:

Schema:

```
  loginEmail(
    email: String!
    password: String!
  ): SignInResponse!
```

```
type SignInResponse {
  accessToken: String!
}
```

GraphQL Code:

```
export type MutationLoginEmailArgs = {
  email: Scalars['String'],
  password: Scalars['String']
};
```

Comment: Try changing it to `.then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<{data:string;}>) => {`

Comment: `{ data }: string` makes no sense. A string is not an object with a `.data` property

Comment: @NickSurmanidze this gives me an error on ```data.loginEmail``` that ```property loginEmail doesn't exist on type data:string``` I tried object too but still the same problem

Comment: Yes you're right. Wild useless try. @Bergi Thought that since both types in the mutation are strings maybe there's some way i can pass strings twice? Keeping in mind an answer to this qs

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TypeScript, you should generate the types for both the data returned by the hook and the variables you pass to it. Type generation can be done using either the [Apollo CLI](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling) or [GraphQL Code Generator](https://graphql-code-generator.com).

Once you've got your types, you can then use them with your hooks as shown [here in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/#typing-hooks). By doing this, you will avoid having to explicitly assign types when consuming the `data` property returned by the hook. You will also add type safety for any variables passed to the hook.

Example usage from the docs:

```
interface RocketInventory {
  id: number;
  model: string;
  year: number;
  stock: number;
}

interface RocketInventoryData {
  rocketInventory: RocketInventory[];
}

interface RocketInventoryVars {
  year: number;
}

const GET_ROCKET_INVENTORY = gql`
  query getRocketInventory($year: Int!) {
    rocketInventory(year: $year) {
      id
      model
      year
      stock
    }
  }
`;

export const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { loading, data } = useQuery<RocketInventoryData, RocketInventoryVars>(
    GET_ROCKET_INVENTORY,
    { variables: { year: 2019 } }
  );
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am still a bit confused. I tried the tools you suggested and edited the qs with the output. However, I still don't know how I can use them in my code. Should I just ```interface LoginEmail {
  email: string;
 password:string;
}``` in my code? But my question is how I can change ```data: any``` exactly

Comment: By passing the correct types to the `useQuery` hook, TypeScript will be able to infer the type for `data` with you doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your data structure corresponds to the following type interface:

```
interface MyDataReponse {
  users: {
   nodes: {
    id: string; // maybe this is number in your case
    firstName:string;
    lastName: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    email: string;
   }[]
  }
}
```

Then on your data:

```
.then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<{data:MyDataReponse;}>) => {
```

Comment: It still gives the same error on loginEmail in the next line. The difference is that it says ```MyDataReponse``` instead of string

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to fix this?